# Is the fingerprint regenerated?

Tags: skin

Let's say you get a a cut on your finger. Will the fingerprint be regenerated to matched your original fingerprint and if so, how?

Comment: Wow! I was just searching about this :D It looks like as far as you don't damage [dermal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermal_papillae) layer, you can regenerate exact [same](http://www.britannica.com/topic/fingerprint#ref262725) pattern.